# Angular html5mode direct link fallback

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, html5-history

I am setting up an Angular site on a LAMP stack, and I have activated html5mode with the following:

```
$locationProvider
    .html5Mode(true)
    .hashPrefix('!#');
```

Coupled with that is my .htaccess setup, which I got from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jxnblk/6137537):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
    RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
</ifModule>
```

Everything works fine for browsers that support the History API, and if I like to my main URL it gracefully falls back to the hashbang. My problem lies if someone links directly to a History-ified link on a browser that does not support it. Example:

**Supports history**

`example.com` => redirects to => `example.com/home/` (`home` is the default page)

`example.com/home/` => loads just fine

**Does not support history**

`example.com` => redirects to => `example.com/!#/home/`

`example.com/home/` => no redirect, everything explodes and kittens perish

My question is ... is there a valid way to ensure the fallback is adhered to when someone links directly to that History-ified link? i.e.:

`example.com/home` => redirects to => `example.com/!#/home`

I have considered .htaccess for redirecting specific browsers, but that seems hacky (and frankly, I wasn't able to get it to work). I have also considered a `<script>` tag in the `<head>` that does a JavaScript test for History API support + lack of !# in URL, and redirects if not.

Both of these seem hacky, so my question is ... is there a proper way to do this? If not, and I need to resort to these hacks, if someone could provide me an .htaccess example at least for IE9, I'd appreciate it.